# Are IpTags supported in azurerm_public_ip

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

from the [Azure public IP address doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-azpublicipaddress?view=azps-5.7.0#code-try-3), we can create a public IP address from ipTag.

```
    $ipTag = New-AzPublicIpTag -IpTagType "FirstPartyUsage" -Tag "/Sql"
    $publicIp = New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name $publicIpName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -AllocationMethod Static -DomainNameLabel $dnsPrefix -Location $location -IpTags $ipTag
```

Does Terraform [azurerm_public_ip](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/public_ip) resource support using ipTag to create a new public IP address? I only see tags but not ipTag.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform added the support in v2.56.0
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v2.56.0/CHANGELOG.md
`azurerm_public_ip` - support for `ip_tags` (#[11270](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/11270))